# Invoking server side function from the client side for dynamically created markup

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I want to call a method that is on the server side by clicking a link or a button that is being dynamically created on the server side. My code dynamically generates the html and changing it to static html is not an option.

```
str.Append("<a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#cmpModal\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">" + Resources.vsk.addasfriend + "</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;");
```

The line above creates a link which upon click opens up a model, the code for which is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cmpModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="acategory" class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="actxt">Add to Friend List</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="model-body">
            <div class="pd_10">
                <div role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="<%= txt_message.ClientID %>">
                                <%= Resources.vsk.message_channel_10 %>:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txt_message" onkeyup="Count_Chars(this,'#tabout_cnt',100);" runat="server"
                                    TextMode="MultiLine" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox><br />
                                <strong id="tabout_cnt">100</strong>
                                <%= Resources.vsk.charsleft %>.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_send" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="btn_send_Click" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The send button in the modal is what calls the server side method. I'm trying to completely get rid of this modal and have the function invoked just by clicking the link. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with AJAX, web sockets, or SignalR?

Comment: @mason I'm familiar with AJAX, know about the other 2 but haven't really used them.

Comment: Great, so try writing an AJAX based solution.

Comment: @mason So am I gonna be using AJAX POST? and what would be the content type?

Comment: Sure, that can work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax on button click. follow link for basics of Ajax=

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
```